# difference of sum of even and odd places in an array using recursion.

Tags: c++

I am trying to create a recursive function which returns elements even sum,odd sum,difference b/w even and odd for an array.

I created an object having these 3 values and have passed it by reference,the syntax is giving no error,but I am getting run time exception(the run window stopped working)

```
  #include < iostream >

  using namespace std;

class o_e_sum 
  {
  public:
    int e_sum;
    int o_sum;
    int diff;

  o_e_sum() 
  {
    e_sum = 0;
    o_sum = 0;
    diff = 0;
  }

 };
void fib(int*,int, o_e_sum& );
int main() 
 {
  int n;
  cin >> n;
  int * p = new int[n];

  for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
  {
    cin >> * (p + i);
  }
  o_e_sum obj;
  fib(p, n, obj);
  cout << obj.diff;

}

void fib(int * n, int s, o_e_sum & ques) 
  {

  if (s == 1) 
   {

    ques.o_sum = * n;
    ques.diff = ques.e_sum - ques.o_sum;

   }
  if (s % 2 == 0) 
   {

    fib(n + 1, s - 1, ques);
    ques.e_sum = ques.e_sum + * n;
    ques.diff = ques.e_sum - ques.o_sum;

   } 
  else 
   {


    fib(n + 1, s - 1, ques);
    ques.o_sum = ques.o_sum + * n;
    ques.diff = ques.e_sum - ques.o_sum;

   }

}
```

Comment: `if (s % 2 == 0) ` Because that is not an `else if`, the recursion never ends.

Comment: 1) "_the syntax is giving no error_" If it would have given an error, you wouldn't be able to run it. 2) Did you try stepping through your code with a debugger?

Comment: Or differently, `if (s == 1)` should have a final `return` to stop recursion.

Comment: Didn't write return for base case.A very crazy mistake.Thanks you all.